# Google Analytics : Sending data to multiple Accounts from a single page

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a requirement of tracking each page view by two different accounts. Lets say X and Y. X is the site on which the tracking code is installed. It gets its site specific data only. Y is another domain which has a stake in many websites including X. Hence, even Y requires the same data. I have set it up as shown in the Analytics Code given here http://seo-website-designer.com/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Multiple-Accounts.

But since X and Y have different domains will it work? P.S : I see the real time data in Y's GA interface, but the active page is /. When multiple X websites start sending the data, I cant differentiate these websites in the report.

Comment: This is a bit confusing - do you want to track the same page with two accounts or track pages on two different domains ? Both is possible but they are quite different things.

Comment: I want to track the same page with two accounts.

Comment: Since the code is not, as far as I understand, implemented on "domain Y" the second domain is absolutely irrelevant to the question and you can follow the instructions from your link. Just remember that you need to to every "push" (pageviews, events, transactions etc.) to both of your trackers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am pushing all the events and pageviews to both the trackers. But my problem is this. Account Y is the secondary tracker for many more websites apart from X. So I simultaneoulsy receive data from all these websites, X1, X2, X3 etc. So how do I differentiate them in the reports in Account Y. I have tried the Display Full URL filter in GA on Account Y. But it completely stop receiving data after I have applied that filter.

Comment: When you look at a data table in the standard reports there is a dropdown labeled "secondary dimension". Select "hostname" and it will show the domain name from whence the hit originated. You can also build a custom segment based on the hostname to view only data from a given domain.

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem like this. In my Domain Y GA account, I had one master view with no filters. In the second view I created I applied a filter to display the full URL as given in this link. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en Hope it helps someone!